# Equilateral triangle in a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have the plane $\pi:x+y-z-1=0$ and the two points $A:(1,1,1), B:(2,1,2)$ as two vertices of an equilateral triangle in the plane $\pi$. How can I find all (I'm assuming only 2?) sets of coordinates for the vertex $C$. *Note that $A,B,\text{ and }C$ lies in $\pi$*.

I've noted that $\vec{AB} = (1,0,1)\iff ||\vec{AB}||=\sqrt2$

---

- Let $Q$ be midpoint for $\vec{AB}$, i.e. its coordinates are $\frac{1}{2}(A+B) = (\frac{3}{2},1,\frac{3}{2})$.
- The plane has the normal vector $\vec{n} = (1,1,-1)$

$\therefore$ The line which goes through $Q$ and $C$ is orthogonal to $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{AB}$. We call this line $L$.

$$\vec{n} \times \vec{AB} = (1,-2,-1)$$

- Using this and that the point $Q$ lies on $L$ we get the equation for $L:$

$$L = (\frac{3}{2}+t,\,1-2t,\,\frac{3}{2}-t)$$

So combining this with the fact that $||\vec{QC}||=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}||\vec{AB}|| = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ as $||\vec{AB}|| = \sqrt{2}$. We can now put $||L(t)|| = ||\vec{QC}||$.

$$||L(t)|| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{2}+t\right)^2 + \left(1-2t\right)^2 + \left(\frac{3}{2}-t\right)^2} = \sqrt{6t^2-4t+\frac{11}{2}} = ||\vec{QC}|| = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$

$\therefore 6t^2-4t+\frac{11}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$

This equation has no real solutions for $t$. What am I to do with this result? Did I do something wrong, or must the solutions contain imaginary units?

Comment: Do you know how to solve this kind of question in the $XY$ plane? do you know how to find affine isometry which take a plain to the $XY$ plane?

Comment: Which one? try to solve this question first in the $XY$ plane.

Comment: The best way to do that in my opinion is to find affine isometry $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which takes your plain to the $XY$ plain, to solve it there and then to use $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I gave you an easier way in my answer.

Comment: I updates the post to add an attempt, at which I failed and would like some help with.

Comment: this is a copy of this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142012/linear-algebra-find-all-possible-positions-of-the-third-corner/1142174#1142174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X: (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2 = 2$

$Y: (x - 2)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 2)^2 = 2$

Let's find $X \cap Y \cap \pi: x + y - z = 1$

$X - Y: (x - 1)^2 +  (z - 1)^2 = (x - 2)^2 + (z - 2)^2$

$x^2 - 2x + 1 + z^2 - 2z + 1 = x^2 - 4x + 4 + z^2- 4z + 4$

$z(x) = 3 - x$

$x + y - 3 + x = 1$

$y(x) = 4 - 2x$

$X: (x - 1)^2 + (4 - 2x - 1)^2 + (3 - x - 1)^2 = 2$

$(x - 1)^2 + (2x - 3)^2 + (x - 2)^2 = 2$

$x^2 - 2x + 1 + 4x^2 - 12x + 9 + x^2 - 4x + 4 = 2$

$6x^2 - 18x + 12 = 0$

$x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0$

$x = 1 \Rightarrow y(x) = 4 - 2 = 2 ; z(x) = 3 - 1 = 2$

$x = 2 \Rightarrow y(x) = 4 - 4 = 0 ; z(x) = 3 - 2 = 1$

Answer (score 2):

Connecnt $A$ and $B$ by a line and midpoint between them by $Q$.
Now find a line which contained in the plane, orthogonal to $AB$ and go through $Q$. Your point $C$ is on that line and the distence from $C$ to $Q$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|AB|$.
Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: I added an attempt where I seem to have gotten the wrong answer, I would love it if you could have a look. Thanks for the help by the way.